# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined, but it's OK with another property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Fetching data from API. Data is like `[{"_id":"someId","data":{"name":"someName", ...}}, ...]`
My state and fetching is like

```
class Table extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        isLoading: true,
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
    })
    fetch(URL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                data: data,
                isLoading: false
            })
            console.log('test ' + this.state.data[29].data.name);
        })
}
```

Last console.log shows the data with no problems. But when I try to render the data the error appears.
My render is

```
render() {
    const tableData = this.state.isLoading ? console.log('-test' + this.state.isLoaded) :
        this.state.data.map(e => <Item key={e._id}
            item={e} data={e.data.name} deleteItem={this.deleteItem} />)
    return (
        <div className='table' >
            {tableData ? tableData : 'loading'}
            < button onClick={this.handleClick} > ADD NEW</button>
        </div >
    )
}
```

And it works fine when I use `data={e._id}` instead of `data={e.data.name}`

Comment: Sounds like `.data` is an array, not an object, so it doesn't have a `.name` property

Comment: If the data comes as you say, I assume the error should be in`console.log('test ' + this.state.data[29].data.name);` since the state updates happen asynchronously and state.data was previously empty

Comment: If not every array element has a `data` property, then for some items, `e.data` will be undefined, resulting in the error. You can try something like `data={e.data ? e.data.name : "fallback"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always check for array to be be not null. What if some element of the array doesn't have data ?

```
const tableData = !this.state.isLoading && this.state.data.map(e => <Item key={e._id} item={e} data={(e.data || {} ).name} deleteItem={this.deleteItem} />)
```